# Troubleshooting ERROR 000814: Invalid file type from arcpy.TableToExcel()?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, excel

I wrote the script below to iterate through a file geodatabase's feature classes and convert them to an excel table. However, it returns the error

```
ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000814: Invalid file type
Failed to execute (TableToExcel)
```

I converted the feature classes to table views but I can't figure out what is wrong with the paramaters. The error is at line 18, which is where the *arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion('table', outname)* operation begins.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r'C:\Parishes\Cameron.gdb'
parish = "Cameron"

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

    if arcpy.Exists('tableview'): 
        arcpy.Delete_management('tableview')

    arcpy.MakeTableView_management(fc, 'tableview') 

    outname = str(fc) + parish + ".xls"

    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion('tableview', outname)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Created "{}" Table export '.format(fc))

arcpy.Delete_management('tableview')
```

Comment: I think your output file name needs to end in `.xls`

Comment: Tried tacking that on to the output string name but it did not work. Thanks though!

Comment: What is `dbSpace`? If this is not a valid folder, you'll likely get the same error.

Comment: Ah ok. This is the file geodatabase it is reading from/set as the environment workspace. Could I set the output path to the output file name variable to force it to save the exported file somewhere else other than that database?

Comment: sure - outname = os.path.join('someotherdirectory',fc.replace(".","_")) (at least i think so - if fc is the feature class name only)

Comment: I tried that but it's still giving me the same error about the parameters being invalid types.

Comment: Still need to add on the .xls extension as per @Mintx

Comment: @DWynne I already tried adding the .xls with and without the folder path name and it still returns the same error.

Comment: @TacoB0t you should really hard code the values in first before messing around with GetParameterAsText(). It makes debugging a lot easier.

Comment: @TacoB0t Can you update your question with the .xls extension and provide an example of `dbSpace`?

Comment: Updated to reflect changes and hardcoded.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a test I suggest trying to change:

```
outname = str(fc) + parish + ".xls"
```

to

```
outname = 'C:\\Parishes\\' + str(fc) + parish + ".xls"
```

I suspect that trying to write a *.xls to a *.gdb (even though that is a folder) is what may be upsetting the tool.

Comment: After dancing around the solution, this was the perfect syntactical combination to get it working! Thanks!

Comment: The combination of comments had the answer an hour ago.

Comment: @DWynne That may be a lesson to the asker about how important it is to keep editing the question to keep it in sync with testing and advice being given. http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/a/3353

Comment: @PolyGeo. My comment was more to the first comment on this answer, not the answer itself. 'Dancing around the solution' seems unfair and downplays the time and contribution of several people.

Comment: @DWynne That was what I figured.  For this question it seemed like a "discussion in comments" was taking the place of comments being used to suggest problems in the question as asked, and then the asker addressing those via edits to the question rather than a convoluted comment trail (aka why I tired of discussion forums).

Comment: PolyGeo is an alright guy, he can have my points. ;)

Answer (score 2):

@PolyGeo's answer is accurate. But I just want to draw attention to the use of table views in the original case; they shouldn't be necessary. Code could be simplified down to something like this:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r'C:\Parishes\Cameron.gdb'
parish = "Cameron"

# use other folder as needed
out_folder = arcpy.env.scratchFolder  

for fc in arcpy.ListFeatureClasses():

    name = os.path.splitext(fc)[0]  # remove extensions if any
    outname = os.path.join(out_folder, "{}{}.xls".format(name, parish))

    arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion(fc, outname)
    arcpy.AddMessage('Created "{}" Table export '.format(fc))
```